# Set different $http url prefix for template and server requests

Tags: angularjs

Basically what I'm trying to do is to set a prefix for all $http server requests (the server url). I tried to use an interceptor, but the problem is that this also affects the template requests:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
    return {
        'request': function (request) {
            request.url = "http://localhost/"+request.url;
            return request || $q.when(request);
        }
    }
});
```

=>

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/templates/main.html
```

I thought about using my own provider (for example $myHttp) which inherit $http, but i don't know how to do this.

So what is a good solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your templates are in the `templates` directory, you could just ignore those in your interceptor.

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($q) {
  return {
    request: function (request) {
      if (request.url.indexOf('templates') === -1) {
        request.url = "http://localhost/" + request.url;
      }
      return request || $q.when(request);
    }
  }
});
```